# What are some good tools to create 3D icons?

Tags: icon, software-recommendation, 3d, resource-recommendations

I really like icons like those created by [SoftFacade.com](http://SoftFacade.com):

[image]

I read the [interview from one of their founders](http://www.iconfinder.com/blog/12/), where he mentions that they use "3d tools" without going into specifics.

Now I am looking for the 3D tools to do such icons. Has anyone an idea of the tools they might be using, or a recommendation to do this kind of job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the big names in 3d modeling are [Blender](http://www.blender.org/features-gallery/) (Free, OSS), [Maya](http://usa.autodesk.com/maya/), and 3ds Max.

Sorry for only posting a couple of links, it won't let me post more! I'll add some if I get enough rep to post more than 2 links.

Comment: Cinema 4D is another one. A lite version of C4D will also be included in Adobe Creative cloud starting in June (2013)

Answer (score 1):

#### A document with recommendations:

You can check this comprehensive [MSDN article on icon creation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742485.aspx). IMHO it is one of most valuable all-basics-in-one-place sources around. It focuses on creation of 3D icons for Microsoft Windows, but the principles are universal.