# Program to make these kinds of 3D liquid acid graphics?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d

I've been searching almost two years and still don't have answer. I would like to know what program could be used for graphic work like this. These crazy, trippy, 3D objects, sometimes combined with simple de-formatted fonts.

Can anyone recommend a software for this type of graphic?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD! There are a lot of tools able to obtain such an image, and you can found a lot of free 3D resources to be combined. See e.g. [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31694/need-advice-on-3d-modelling-tool), [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1755/what-are-some-good-tools-to-create-3d-icons), [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2589/3d-character-modeling-tool) and also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_3D_modeling_software).

Comment: Any respectable 3d modelling application will be fine for this type of work and same goes for 3d renderers.

Comment: There is no such program that restricts itself to "trippy images only," so googling for "3d trippy acid" probably makes it harder to find what you are looking for. try "open source 3D modeling"

Answer (score 2):

My most educated guess tells me that the program used to make this is [Cinema 4D](http://www.maxon.net/en/home.html), which is a paid program. Now here is your option look into [Blender](https://www.blender.org) which is a free open source 3D program that can do exactly the same as every other program available.

With a little Google Foo and some well invested time, you should be cooking relatively easily!

Good luck, and always save and find something to do while rendering!